# Two layouts and findViewById

Tags: android, layout, view, android-inflate, findviewbyid

I have two layouts - activity_main.xml and select.xml(transparent). In my MainActivity class I have:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and after that:

```
view = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.select, null);

btnPrev = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
btnNext = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnOk = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

btnPrev.setOnClickListener(this);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And the buttons appear but seem to do nothing. The onClick() method is fully implemented so I think there is something wrong in mixing the two layouts (select.xml is on top of activity_main.xml). Any advice?

EDIT: This image(select.xml):
[image]

Should be on top of this image(activity_main.xml):[image]

When a menu item "select" is clicked.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.whistle_change:
            Intent a = new Intent(this, WhistleSelect.class);
            startActivity(a);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:

            break;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Why is your select.xml on top? It's probably blocking any touch events directed to your buttons, or anything in your activity.xml

Comment: select.xml consists of three buttons which are used to change the background in activity_main.xml depending on which button is pressed.

Comment: Can you add some more code? its difficult to figure out your problem..

Comment: @Nikola yes, please post your xml files, this would be helpful

Comment: oh my bad, thought the buttons were in the activity_main.xml. So, suggestion, why not just use a frame layout to directly place your buttons in the activity layout?

Comment: Use frame layout that is better for you in this case.......